# how to use leader key as part of package prefix

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, evil-mode

Can't find info anywhere else. I have `,` as a leader key.

Trying to set prefix keys for `prespective` and for `workgroups` packages (emacs):

```
(use-package perspective
  :demand t
  :init
  (setq persp-keymap-prefix (kbd ", c")) ;; not working
  (customize-set-variable 'persp-keymap-prefix (kbd ", c")) ;; not working either
  (setq persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "<leader> c")) ;; nope
  (setq persp-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-x x")) ;; working..
  :config ...
```

Tried different variants, but nothing works, sadly i haven't learned elisp yet, please help

---

## Solution

```lisp
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd ",z") 'perspective-map)
```

**Thanks to *picle rick***

Also if the solution above won't work for you in some reason, here is another one:

```lisp
  (setq persp-mode-prefix-key (kbd "C-x x"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd ",z") (kbd "C-x x"))
```

[source](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc13)

Answer (score 0):

Prefix keys typically need to be defined before the package is loaded to take effect, since the keymap is populated at that time.  Otherwise, special action needs to taken to repopulate the keymap with the new prefix value.

So, you could stick with the configuration you currently have, but you would need to make sure any `require`s related to those packages happen after the `setq` (that would be my personal preference).

Alternatively, you could use the customize functions/UI (at least for the `wg-prefix-key`, I didn't look into `presp`).  `defcustom` variables that are defined with special properties, like `:set`, can run code to when various changes are made to variable, eg. updating its value.  This would involve some <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize` stuff interactively, or in code,

```
(customize-set-variable 'wg-prefix-key (kbd ", a"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it didn't help, i updated my question with some details, i'll be grateful if you will help

Comment: @sad I don't use `use-package`, but why is your config for `wg` in the perspective section?  Did you try using `M-x customize`? That is probably the easiest option until you get a better feel for the language.  You should also be able to try `M-: (customize-set-prefix ...)`

Comment: @sad I'm also not an `evil-mode` user, and just realized that customizing those [maps](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc8) likely requires special treatment

Comment: `(customize-set-variable 'persp-mode-prefix-key (kbd ", z"))` actually sets this variable to `, z`, but when i try to use it, i get `, z is undefined`. Same goes for `M-x customize-set-value` --> `persp-mode-prefix-key` (there is no 'persp-keymap-prefix' as stated in their doc.) --> `, z` -- not working, even tho it **is** set to `, z `

Comment: @sad yea, from a quick look at evil, you probably need to be defining it on one of the evil maps.  perspective already defines a `prefix-map`, so  something like `(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "a") 'perspective-map)`, but now this would go after `require`ing perspective, since you want the keymap to already be defined at this point

Comment: @piclerick, i edited my question, your solution works for me, thank you very much